# How can i get email and password value from this output which is response from web service in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios

Since i convert webservice response into Json and assign into NSDictionary. When i print out the contents in dictionary then it gives the output below. My problem is How can i get email and password value from this output?

Key is post, Value is

```
(
        {
        post =         {
            "active_flag" = Y;
            email = "g.amit@jasapp.com";
            "first_name" = amit;
            "last_name" = gupta;
            "member_id" = 17;
            password = amitgupta;
        };
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, if the `NSDictionary` you are creating from JSON is named `jsonDict`, the following code should work:

```
NSDictionary *post = [jsonDict objectForKey:@"post"];
NSString *email = [post objectForKey:@"email"];
NSString *password = [post objectForKey:@"password"];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 NSMutableDictionary *temDict = [self.YourAarray objectAtIndex:0];  
 NSlog(@"%@",[temDict  objectForKey:@"email"]);
 NSlog(@"%@",[currentHighscore objectForKey:@"password"]);
```

Comment: Rather than only post a block of code, please *explain* why this code solves the problem posed. Without an explanation, this is not an answer.

Comment: Please tell me how can i convert dictionary into array

Comment: Please tell me is this array or dictionary??

Comment: this is dictionary of array ..in my code i Get 1 record from  array and it is store into temDict and then values of email and password get by its keys

Comment: @amitshinik - humm ....tum to india ke hi ho bhai....samaj hi jaoge hahahaha :D lol

Comment: NSString *em;  NSString *pw;  NSArray *arr=[(NSDictionary *)[strResult JSONValue] objectForKey:@"post"];
    NSDictionary *dict=[arr objectAtIndex:0];
    em=[(NSDictionary *)[dict objectForKey:@"post"] objectForKey:@"email"];
    pw=[(NSDictionary *)[dict objectForKey:@"post"] objectForKey:@"password"];